# Is $F=-\nabla V$ a form of the least action principle?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, conservative-field

Only for conservative systems, of course.

Comment: It simply follows from the *definition* of potential energy as the line integral of force, and thus contains no dynamics whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the equation $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla V$, where $\mathbf{F}$ is the force and $V$ is the potential energy, can be viewed as a manifestation of the **least action principle** for conservative systems.

The **principle of least action**, specifically Hamilton's principle, states that the actual path taken by a system between two configurations is the one for which the **action integral** is stationary (usually a minimum). The action $S$ is defined as the integral of the Lagrangian $L$ over time, where the Lagrangian is the difference between the kinetic and potential energies, $L = T - V$.

To connect $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla V$ with the least action principle, we can start by considering the **Euler-Lagrange equation**, which is derived from the least action principle. For a particle with potential $V$ and kinetic energy $T = \frac{1}{2}m\mathbf{v}^2$, where $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity, the Lagrangian is $L = T - V$.

The Euler-Lagrange equation is given by

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_i} \right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i} = 0
$$

for each generalized coordinate $q_i$ and its time derivative $\dot{q}_i$.

Now, let's derive $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla V$ using the Euler-Lagrange equation:

1. **Lagrangian Formulation**: Consider a system with a single particle, so $q_i$ is just the position $\mathbf{r}$, and $\dot{q}_i$ is the velocity $\mathbf{v}$.
2. **Compute Derivatives**:

   - The derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to velocity $\dot{\mathbf{r}}$ is the momentum: $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{r}}} = m\mathbf{v}$$.
   - The derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to position $\mathbf{r}$ is $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{r}} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial \mathbf{r}}$$ (since the kinetic energy $T$ does not depend on position).
3. **Euler-Lagrange Equation**:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}(m\mathbf{v}) - (-\frac{\partial V}{\partial \mathbf{r}}) = 0
$$

Simplifying this, we get

$$
m\mathbf{a} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial \mathbf{r}}
$$

where $\mathbf{a}$ is the acceleration.

4. **Identify the Force**: By Newton's second law, $m\mathbf{a}$ is the force $\mathbf{F}$, so we have

$$
\mathbf{F} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial \mathbf{r}}
$$

which is equivalent to $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla V$, for conservative forces.

Hence, the relation $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla V$ is indeed derivable from the principle of least action, specifically through the Euler-Lagrange equation applied to a conservative system. This demonstrates that the notion of forces in classical mechanics can be recast in terms of energy minimization principles, aligning with the broader framework of least action principles in physics.

Comment: Thank you! I didn’t know the derivation was so straightforward :)

Comment: Of course! If you have any further questions, please let me know!